# How to resolve a hostname via nsswitch?

Tags: shell-script, dns

I want to test in a script whether a hostname resolves to something other than 127.0.0.1 as a pre-flight test for an install script. The tools I know (dig, nslookup) specifically query DNS. In my situation a correct entry in /etc/hosts is a valid configuration. So the question is:

Is there a dig-like tool, ideally already on the system, that does the full name-resolution process via nsswitch.conf, like (for example) ping does?

```
dig my-test-server-that-only-exists-in-etc-hosts
```

returns NXDOMAIN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This already has an answer on SU:

[Bash: lookup an IP for a host name, including /etc/hosts in search](https://superuser.com/questions/305939/bash-lookup-an-ip-for-a-host-name-including-etc-hosts-in-search)

Basically, you use

```
getent ahosts host_name
```

where host_name can either be an entry in your `/etc/hosts`, in which case it will resolve to that, or a host that your DNS can resolve.

Quoting the `getent(1)` man page:

> **ahosts**
>                  When no key is provided, use sethostent(3), gethostent(3),
>                       and endhostent(3) to enumerate the hosts  database.   This
>                       is  identical  to using hosts.  When one or more key argu‐
>                       ments are provided, pass each key in succession to  getad‐
>                       drinfo(3)  with  the address family AF_UNSPEC, enumerating
>                       each socket address structure returned